ESLint rule for not showing errors for typescript type definitions
I have a workflow that checks for ESLint errors by running yarn lint command.
Here is how the workflow looks like:
name: Build and deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
env:
  app_name: support_case_ui
  bucket_name_dev: support-ui-static-files-dev
  bucket_name_prod: support-ui-static-files-prod
  IS_FEATURE: ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' && github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'}}
  IS_DEV: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
  NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.READER_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.x
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: .yarn/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Set environment variables for frontend build
        # Use environment variables from feature just for the build to go green. Using actual env variables in deploy step
        run: cat env/.env.dev >> $GITHUB_ENV 
      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn --immutable
      - name: Check lint
        run: yarn lint
      - name: Run tests and build
        run: yarn test && yarn build

  deploy-to-feature:
    name: Deploy to feature
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.x
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: .yarn/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn --immutable
      - name: Set environment variables for build
        run: cat env/.env.dev >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build app
        run: yarn build
      - name: Login GCP dev
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICEUSER_KEY_DEV }}
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
      - name: Upload static files to feature GCP bucket
        run: gsutil -m rsync -R -d dist gs://${{env.bucket_name_dev}}/${{env.app_name}}/feature/static

  deploy-to-main:
    name: Deploy to main
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.x
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: .yarn/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn --immutable
      - name: Set environment variables for build
        run: cat env/.env.main >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build app
        run: yarn build
      - name: Login GCP dev
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICEUSER_KEY_DEV }}
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
      - name: Upload static files to dev GCP bucket
        run: gsutil -m rsync -R -d dist gs://${{env.bucket_name_dev}}/${{env.app_name}}/main/static
  deploy-to-prod:
    name: Deploy to prod
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.x
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: .yarn/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn --immutable
      - name: Set environment variables for build
        run: cat env/.env.prod >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build app
        run: yarn build
      - name: Login GCP dev
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICEUSER_KEY_PROD }}
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
      - name: Upload static files to prod GCP bucket
        run: gsutil -m rsync -R -d dist gs://${{env.bucket_name_prod}}/${{env.app_name}}/static

For this line of code:
type STEPSTYPE = { [key in Stepper]: number } | { [key in CaseStepper]: number };

I get an error when I run a workflow job:
Error:   52:86  error  'key' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

But if I run yarn lint locally on my computer I don't get any errors. It runs without any errors:
yarn run v1.22.19
$ eslint ./src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx} package.json --quiet
✨  Done in 3.76s.

Is there any lint rule where I can avoid error for typescript type definitions, other than no-unused-vars? I would still like to get errors for unused vars, but in my case it is not a var, just a type that the error is being thrown for.
This is my current ESLint configuration:
module.exports = {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        sourceType: "module", // Allows for the use of imports
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
        },
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect", // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
        },
        "json/sort-package-json": ["name", "version", "private", "scripts", "dependencies", "devDependencies"],
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "json-format", "simple-import-sort", "unused-imports"],
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    ],
    rules: {
        "sort-imports": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
        "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
        "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "warn",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
            "warn",
            { vars: "all", varsIgnorePattern: "^_", args: "after-used", argsIgnorePattern: "^_" },
        ],
        eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"],
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ["*.js"],
            rules: {
                "no-undef": "off",
            },
        },
    ],
};

Also, not sure why do I get 2 different outputs locally and in GitHub?
I ran yarn install locally and workflow is running it as well, so that shouldn't be a different dependency versions issue. How can I fix this?

Maybe your dependencies aren't up-to-date. Try running yarn install before running the linter

I did run it, still got the same

This could be caused by a syntax error in the part of your code you haven't provided.

Sharing your workflow file might help too.

Github action is clearly pointing to where the linting error is, this is no syntax error issue.

@Leff can you share your entire workflow?

@ShaykiAbramczyk sure, I added workflow content

There's no such rule, it's just one no-used-vars rule. Have you considered changing the type (keeping it still the same) or even adding a lint ignore for the particular statement?

@Leff can you see in the logs what is the yarn version?

@Leff would you be open to modifying the configs e.g. .eslintrc.js, .eslintrc.json

@DerekRoberts yes, I would. I have added my current configuration to the question.

Are you sure it's this line that causes an error? The one you provided only has 82 symbols, while the error is on 52:86.

If this is it, you can configure @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/). The easiest option would be to disable it as well, but I think you'd like to set the varsIgnorePattern: "^_" and rename key to _key


Node.js may run different versions of eslint or
TypeScript. In your workflow file, node-version: is specified as
20.x. You can check this
The caches used in GitHub Actions can cause problems. You can check this too.
As last you can compare the versions installed in both environments using the yarn list --pattern eslint command.

I may provide you one more thing that I using everytime is; eslint config
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_", "varsIgnorePattern": "^_", "ignoreRestSiblings": true, "caughtErrorsIgnorePattern": "^_", "ignoreRestSiblings": true, "destructuredArrayIgnorePattern": "^_", "ignoreTypeReferences": true }]
As mentioned in the comments, you can make sure that the packages are installed properly
Make sure that the dependencies are installed in the same way as in workflow by running the yarn install --immutable command.
I hope this helps you solve your problem.

try changing your type to
type STEPSTYPE = { [key in keyof Stepper]: number } | { [key in keyof CaseStepper]: number };

